# cake php issue while user read function

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Hi this is a cakephp issue that I am facing.

I added a field company in customer

when I try to read data

```
$this->data = $this->Customer->read(null, $id);
```

using this.

It show me internal error

Please can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new field for your **Customer** table, try deleting your model cache and check,

```
$this->data = $this->Customer->read(null, $id);
```

And it should work

Answer (score 0):

The another way is just change the debug value from 2 to 0 then execute your code, and again change it from 0 to 2 in app/Config/core.php file. It worked for me.

In this case you don't need to clean your model cache file from app/tmp/cache/models folder.